# Something (presumably, mkswap) corrupted my btrfs partition

Tags: arch-linux, btrfs, swap

I am kind of new to arch (endeavour os particularly), but i am not sure that the problem is in the system. In short, my laptop won’t go to hibernation after it’s lid is closed because it didn’t have a swap file to save session to. I then proceed with creating by guide written on arch wiki, using command `mkswap`. After doing some stuff described on arch wiki, i tried to hibernate my laptop, but nothing happened. For some days, my system worked fine, but then i tried to update using yay and reboot. Laptop didn’t reboot but it has loaded that session from when i tried to hibernate it. And after rebooting from that session, it didn’t boot up. The problem was with the system partition, but `fsck` did fix it. Then it didn’t boot because it couldn’t mount that corrupted btrfs partition. For information, problematic btrfs partition is right before linux system partition, and contain important data without backups.

My hypothesis is that mkswap has tried to make up swap partition by squeezing system partition, but somehow it affected btrfs partition, and i believe, it didn’t recognize it.

This is the output from btrfs check:

```
Opening filesystem to check...
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 246038528, bytenr mismatch, want=246038528, have=0
ERROR: could not setup csum tree
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

Important note that system partition is fully functional, and i am using my lap in dualboot, where w10 see that btrfs partition corrupted too.

Tried btrfs check --repair:

```
Starting repair.
Opening filesystem to check...
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 246038528 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 246038528, bytenr mismatch, want=246038528, have=0
WARNING: could not setup csum tree, skipping it
parent transid verify failed on 71958528 wanted 45315 found 45751
parent transid verify failed on 71958528 wanted 45315 found 45751
parent transid verify failed on 71958528 wanted 45315 found 45751
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 201768960 wanted 45297 found 45330
parent transid verify failed on 201768960 wanted 45297 found 45330
parent transid verify failed on 201768960 wanted 45297 found 45330
Ignoring transid failure
checksum verify failed on 202014720 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 202014720 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
checksum verify failed on 202014720 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xb6bde3e4
bad tree block 202014720, bytenr mismatch, want=202014720, have=0
ERROR: failed to read block groups: Input/output error
ERROR: cannot open file system
```

Tried `btrfs restore -v` (skipping wall of repetitive text about items):

```
ERROR: root [5 0] level 0 does not match 2

Could not open root, trying backup super
ERROR: superblock bytenr 274877906944 is larger than device size 101518934016
Could not open root, trying backup super
```

I even tried resizing it in GParted, but it didn’t allow due to errors.

EDIT: So... is there any way to restore data from it?

EDIT2: the way i have tried to create swap file was:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
sudo mkswap /swapfile
free
sudo swapon /swapfile
grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
```

Important note: i forgot to edit /etc/fstab so that it would contain info about swap partition, but the thing is swap partition wasn't created, rather my system part and btrfs part (with just data) was f-ed up.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Examples: "why did this happen? is my hypothesis about swap right?", "how can I fix the filesystem?", "how can I properly create a swap file on btrfs?", "how should I proceed to recover as much data as possible?". These are not equivalent one to another, do not let us guess what your question is. Please [edit] and ask one well-defined, explicit question.

Comment: I did something similar several years ago and I "recovered" by abandoning the old filesystem and creating a new one from scratch. Swap on btrfs is possible, but you need to follow the right procedure: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1442752/432690) or read about `mkswapfile` in `man 8 btrfs-filesystem`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You're right, sorry, didn't even notice how messy my question is

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the thing is i didn't want to make swap on the btrfs partition, but somehow it did corrupt it. Maybe is there a way to restore files? I am not talking about the whole fs, but there are some files that i really need

Comment: "how can i fix it? Why did this happened and how to prevent it in the future?" are in fact three questions. IMO the latter two are closely related but "how can I fix it?" is distinct. This site works best for orthogonal questions, one question per post. If I were you, I would concentrate here on recovering the data (this seems to be your primary concern); and if I wanted answers to "why did this happened and how to prevent it in the future?", I would ask a separate question (although your description of what you did is rather vague, it's not even clear if the swap was a file on btrfs or what).

Comment: I mean "I then proceed with creating by guide written on arch wiki, using command `mkswap`. After doing some stuff described on arch wiki, i tried to hibernate my laptop, but nothing happened" is vague. To really answer "why?" and "how to prevent?" we need links to the guide, the wiki, plus (or at least) the exact commands you run.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski edited main post so it contain the way i tried to create swap. It is not correct way to create swap with btrfs, but it is not btrfs i wanted to create swap on. The guide is literally "Swap" page on arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/swap

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "it is not btrfs i wanted to create swap on"? What do you mean by "my system part and btrfs part"? Is `/` on btrfs or not? Are there two btrfs filesystems ("system part and …")? If `/swapfile` was on btrfs then `sudo swapon /swapfile` could be enough to start corrupting the filesystem. (2) (Meta note) There is no need to reinvent the [revision history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/772183/revisions) by writing "EDIT" or "EDIT2".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski No, `/swapfile` was on system ext4 partition

Comment: OK. Just in case please show the output of `findmnt /` and `findmnt /the/mountpoint/of/btrfs`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 
```
TARGET
  SOURCE         FSTYPE OPTIONS
/ /dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   rw,noatime,stripe=32
```
btrfs partition is not mounted and could not due to errors

Comment: To be clear: `mkswap /swapfile` should have done nothing to any partition, it worked with the regular file. A swapfile on ext4 is not a dangerous thing. There should have been no connection between the swapfile and the btrfs filesystem, unless the partitions overlap. The disturbing thing is "it has loaded that session from when i tried to hibernate it". I suppose when some old session got unhibernated, it expected the filesystems in the old state, but the previous operations had already modified them. This may be the cause of corruption, not the swapfile.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski but i did no changes to the filesystem at all since that moment, only updated using `yay`. By the way, it has even loaded that session's terminal history

Comment: OK, I won't argue. I cannot help you with data recovery, I hope you get help from other users, good luck. To increase your chances you should rebuild the question, so it's immediately clear (for now it's not) that there is ext4 and btrfs, that the swapfile was on the former, and what happened to each at what stage.